# Postgres docker container still listening at 5432 after port mapping

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose

Background: I'm trying to configure a local dev instance of a service with two docker postgres containers: one for dev and one that I can run pytest integration tests on. The app is built using fastapi and sqlalchemy with asyncpg.

I've got a couple issues here: the first is a problem running my healthcheck, and the second is that I've instructed the postgres container to listen at port 5433 instead of port 5432, but `docker ps` still shows the container has an active port at 5432. I think this is causing problems trying to connect to this test container. Note the unhealthy status as determined by healthcheck:

[image]

Note the healthcheck test line below: when the `-u inclasstoday` flag is included, it yields an unhealthy status above. However, if I connect to the docker container from my local machine (using `docker-exec it test-db sh` and then run the same command `pg_isready -p 5433 -u inclasstoday`, I get the following error:

[image]

```
/ # pg_isready -p 5433
/var/run/postgresql:5433 - accepting connections
/ # pg_isready -p 5433 -u inclasstoday
/usr/local/bin/pg_isready: unrecognized option: u
pg_isready: hint: Try "pg_isready --help" for more information.
```

However, connecting with only `pg_isready -p 5433` works. When I try to edit my docker-compose.yml file to just use this command as a healthcheck, I then get the error:
`test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:30:47.520 UTC [196] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`
Also note that this db log output is caused by the above `pg_isready -p 5433` command executed inside the docker container from my local machine.

Included my docker-compose.yml file and a log dump below.

#### Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=fastapi_traefik
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=fastapi_traefik
      - APP_CONFIG_FILE=local
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; cd backend; echo "RUNNING ALEMBIC MIGRATIONS"; alembic upgrade head; cd ..; uvicorn backend.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --reload'
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    secrets:
      - db_password
    networks:
      - dock-db-test

  db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: dev-db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=fastapi_traefik
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=fastapi_traefik
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U fastapi_traefik" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    secrets:
      - db_password
    networks:
      - dock-db-test

  test_db:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: test-db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=inclasstoday
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=inclasstoday1
      - POSTGRES_DB=student-data_test
      - APP_CONFIG_FILE=test
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD="trust"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres_data_test:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5433:5433
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -p 5433 -u inclasstoday" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - dock-db-test
    command: postgres -c port=5433



volumes:
  postgres_data:
  postgres_data_test:


secrets:
  db_password:
    file: db.password.txt

networks:
  dock-db-test:
    external: false
    name: dock-db-test
```

#### Log dump:

```
➜  travelapp git:(async) ✗ docker-compose up
Starting dev-db  ... done
Starting test-db ... done
Starting travelapp_backend_1 ... done
Attaching to dev-db, test-db, travelapp_backend_1
dev-db     |
dev-db     | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
dev-db     |
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.618 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.622 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.623 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.630 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.660 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-08-08 19:25:12 UTC
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.878 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.884 UTC [62] LOG:  redo starts at 0/19A0F80
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.885 UTC [62] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/19A0FB8: wanted 24, got 0
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.885 UTC [62] LOG:  redo done at 0/19A0F80 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.891 UTC [58] LOG:  checkpoint starting: end-of-recovery immediate wait
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.902 UTC [58] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.004 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.012 s; sync files=2, longest=0.001 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
dev-db     | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.916 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
test-db    |
test-db    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
test-db    |
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.759 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10) 12.2.1 20220924, 64-bit
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.762 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5433
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.762 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5433
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.767 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433"
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.783 UTC [62] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-08-08 19:27:17 UTC
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:29:41.804 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
backend_1  | RUNNING ALEMBIC MIGRATIONS
backend_1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
backend_1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
backend_1  | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/app']
backend_1  | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
backend_1  | INFO:     Started reloader process [12] using WatchFiles
backend_1  | INFO:     Started server process [14]
backend_1  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
backend_1  | INFO:     Application startup complete.
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:30:47.520 UTC [196] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:33:55.982 UTC [538] FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:34:41.809 UTC [58] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
test-db    | 2023-08-08 19:34:41.879 UTC [58] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.017 s, sync=0.003 s, total=0.070 s; sync files=2, longest=0.002 s, average=0.001 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=0 kB
```

Expected the postgres port to no longer be accepting connections at port 5432 for test-db, and to be able to connect using the user -u flag in ps_isready.

Comment: Use capital U instead of u for the user name: `-U username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passed an invalid parameter. You passed **-u** (with lowercase), the correct one is **-U** (with uppercase). Also, you can pass a database name.
Try the following command:

```
test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -p 5433 -U inclasstoday -d student-data_test" ]
```